# Parameter not valid - System.argumentexception - Image Handling

Tags: c#, image, exception

the following piece of code worked fine all day yesterday

```
public Image getImage()
    {
        String connectionString = "URL GOES HERE, CANT POST WORK DATA";
        Image img;
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(connectionString) as HttpWebRequest;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            img= Image.FromStream(reader.BaseStream);
        }

        return img;
    }
```

It gets an image from a webservice provided by work, i used it a lot yesterday for the day but now all i get is the exception stated in the header on the line

```
img= Image.FromStream(reader.BaseStream);
```

the problem is its working for everyone else apart from me (you can manually type the url in to your browser and it displays the image in there, this is not working for me either)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1) The StreamReader is of not use, it's only used for Text streams, you can use response.GetResponseStream() directly

2) The doc for Image.FromStream available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx) says "You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.", so you must not create the stream with the 'using' statement, as it will be closed at block end.

Comment: i dont mean to dismiss what you have said, and i promise i am  not, its just that it worked all day yesterday using the code i have above, what could have suddenly made it stop?

Comment: Hmmm... bugs tend to hide themselves, so buggy code may work and most of the time, it *will*, so it's harder to find :)

Comment: so you suggest changing streamreader reader = ..... to just a direct call to response.GetResponseStream() to replace that line, remove the using clause, but then how do i assign my img variable with no reader object anymore